# How to wc only readable files on a Linux command line? Showing no permission errors for unreadable files

Tags: linux, command-line

So I am in a Linux course and having trouble figuring out this question. I need to come up with a command that a user can execute to display word counts for all readable files in a folder, without displaying any error messages. I'm sure this is simple but I can find it anywhere.

Comment: surely if asked on a course, there has been some content around that area. Pay more attention rather than relying on someone else!

Comment: You need to use `for` loop over `ls` then test if it's a regular file `test -f` if so count the words using `wc -w`. Combining those together is left for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find /home/jon/ -maxdepth 1 -readable -type f -exec wc -w {} \;`

You can use `find` with `-type f` for files only, `-maxdepth 1` so that `find` doesn't search in sub-directories, `-readable` so it only searches readable files and `wc -w` to count the words in the files:

```
[ 08:36 jon@host ~ ]$ find /home/jon/ -maxdepth 1 -readable -type f -exec wc -w {} \;
6 /home/jon/.screenrc
27 /home/jon/.bash_profile
418 /home/jon/.xsession-errors
105 /home/jon/.lesshst
3 /home/jon/.bash_logout
49 /home/jon/.toprc
102 /home/jon/.zshrc
1916 /home/jon/.viminfo
2661 /home/jon/.bash_history
17 /home/jon/.bashrc
```

To show that the `wc -w` is correct:

```
[ 08:37 jon@host ~ ]$ cat .screenrc
multiuser on
acladd root
altscreen on

[ 08:40 jon@host ~ ]$ cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH

[ 08:40 jon@host ~ ]$ cat .bash_logout
# ~/.bash_logout
/usr/bin/clear

[ 08:40 jon@host ~ ]$ cat .bashrc
# .bashrc
# User specific aliases and functions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

From [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> ```
>    -maxdepth levels
>           Descend  at  most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line
>           arguments.  -maxdepth 0
>            means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.
>
>
>    -readable
>           Matches files which are readable.  This takes into account access control lists and other per-
>           missions artefacts which the -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2)  system
>           call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which do UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many
>           systems implement access(2) in the client's kernel and so cannot make use of the  UID  mapping
>           information held on the server.
>
>    -type c
>           File is of type c:
>
>           b      block (buffered) special
>
>           c      character (unbuffered) special
>
>           d      directory
>
>           p      named pipe (FIFO)
>
>           f      regular file
>
>           l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -follow option is in  effect,
>                  unless  the  symbolic link is broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
>                  is in effect, use -xtype.
>
>           s      socket
>
>           D      door (Solaris)
> ```

Comment: This gives the word counts correctly, but still displays 'permission denied' errors for non-readable files.

Comment: Thanks @user993805, edited to add `-readable` to the command.